# Blocked Gibbs Sampling using Forward / Backward Algorithm

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, hidden-markov-model, gibbs

I am new to machine learning and have been reading about gibbs sampling. From my understanding, a Gibbs algorithm samples a single variable iteratively conditioned on all other variables. In blocked Gibbs sampling, I block a subset of variables and sample iteratively conditioned on other variables. I understand both Gibbs and blocked Gibbs but I am confused on why Forward-Backward algorithm is needed for blocked Gibbs on a HMM.  Can somone clarify my confusion? Could someone also provide example of forward/backward as it relates to Gibbs sampling?

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your parameters $\theta$, your time series of observations $y_{1:T}$, and your hidden states $x_{1:T}$.

Blocked-Gibbs sampling targets the full posterior $p(\theta,x_{1:T}|y_{1:T})$. It alternates between sampling $X_{1:T}^i \sim p(x_{1:T}|y_{1:t},\theta)$ and $\theta^i \sim p(\theta|x_{1:T},y_{1:T})$. It is called Blocked Gibbs because all of the states are blocked together and sampled all at once. You need the Forward-Backward algorithm to do the first one: to sample from $p(x_{1:T}|y_{1:t},\theta)$.

And [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3085787.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A0b7a0627e55e531a47933aa972b94d8d)'s a paper.